# xslt escape angle brackets

Tags: html, escaping, xslt-2.0

I would like to replace a '.\s+\w+' sequence with a literal

Here is what I have:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace($fdesc,'[.][ ]+\w+','<br/>')" />
```

Here is what I get as an error:

> Error on line 33 column 57 of file:/Users/seth/Documents/EmausCCB/XSL/form_list.xsl:
>     SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: The value of attribute "select" associated with an
>     element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.
>   Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.

If I do :

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace($fdesc,'[.][ ]+\w+','br')" />
```

I get the expected results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you want to create a `br` result element you can't use the `replace` function as it returns a string and not elements.

Use `analyze-string` instead e.g.

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="$fesc" regex="[.][ ]+\w+">
  <xsl:matching-substring>
    <br/>
  </xsl:matching-substring>
  <xsl:non-matching-substring>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:non-matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```

As for the XML parse error, the right syntax would be `<xsl:value-of select="replace($fdesc,'[.][ ]+\w+','&lt;br/&gt;')" />`, but that would still return a string and not an element node.